# When are a set and its complement both syndetic?

Tags: combinatorics, semigroups, ramsey-theory

Let $G$ be a semigroup. A subset $S\subseteq G$ is **syndetic** if $G$ is covered by finitely many translates of $S$: *i.e.* there are elements $g_1,\ldots,g_m\in G$ such that $G=Sg_1\cup \cdots\cup Sg_m$.

If $G$ is a group $H$ is a subgroup of finite index then of course any coset $Hg$ is syndetic. Any set containing such $Hg$ would also be syndetic, since the family of syndetic sets is upper-closed.

Syndetic sets are viewed as "combinatorially large" sets.

---

**Connection to dynamics**

Here are two theorems connecting this "combinatorial large"-ness to return sets in dynamical systems. They concern orbits $Gx=\{gx : g\in G\}$ intersecting with open/closed sets.

> **Theorem 1.** If $G$ is a group acting on a compact space $X$, then for any open set $U$ and point $x_0\in X$, the return set $N:=\{g\in G: gx_0\in U\}$ is syndetic.
>
> **Theorem 2.** If $\varphi:X\rightarrow X$ is a continuous mapping of a *noetherian* space $X$, then for any closed set $C$ and point $x_0\in X$, the return set $M:=\{n\geq 0: \varphi^n(x_0)\in C\}$ either has zero density or contains an infinite arithmetic progression.

(A **noetherian space** is one satisfying the ascending chain condition on open sets. These are always compact, but never Hausdorff unless they are finite and discrete. Algebraic varieties are important examples.)

Theorem 1 is about open sets while Theorem 2 is about closed sets. So we can combine them: if $U=X\setminus C$, we get $N=\mathbb{N}_0\setminus M$.

If we view an arithmetic progression as a coset of a subsemigroup of $(\mathbb{N}_0,+)$, then we can view the combinations of Theorem 1 and 2 as saying: $N$ is syndetic, and its complement is either sparse or contains a coset of a subsemigroup.

The first alternative makes sense: "$N$ is large and its complement is thin." But the second one says "$N$ is large, but so is its complement." One example I can think of is when $G=\mathbb{N}_0$ and $N$ is the set of even numbers. Then the complement the odd numbers, which is a coset of a subsemigroup of finite index.

Is this the only way a set and its complement can both by syndetic?

---

This leads me to the following purely combinatorial question.

> **Question.** Suppose that $S$ and and its complement $S^c=G\setminus S$ are both syndetic (in $G$). Must $S$ contain a coset of a subsemigroup of $G$?

Some common terminology: $S$ is **thick** if its complement $S^c$ is *not* syndetic. So in the above question we are trying to show that if $S$ is syndetic but not thick, then $S$ contains a translate of a subsemigroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Thue-Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) $0110100110010110\dotsc$ gives a counterexample. Denoting the $n$th term of this sequence by $a_n$, let $S$ be the set of all those indices $n$ with $a_n=0$; thus, the complement $S^c$ is the set of those $n$ with $a_n=1$. Both $S$ and $S^c$ are syndetic, as the original sequence does not contain any run of three or more consecutive elements. On the other hand, neither $S$ nor $S^c$ contains a coset, as the Thue-Morse sequence is known to show cancellation on arithmetic progressions.

Comment: I wonder if your set $S$ can arise as the return set of some group action on a noetherian space.